# Discord.py massban

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been working really hard with a massban command but it doesn't work. Here is the code. Basically it doesn't do anything and I get no error in console.

```
@bot.command()
async def massban(ctx, user: discord.User ):
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await user.ban(user)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "It doesn't work" is not really helpful. Please say what does not work or share your log/traceback after executing the command.

Comment: Alright I edited it.

Comment: Your edit does not really makes sense as you still did not say what is not working/did not share your log/traceback... Do you want to ban all users on a server or just multiple accounts chosen by you?

Comment: All users in the server and I get no traceback it just doesn't work

Comment: You have a generic exception that is swallowing any errors and passing. That's an antipattern for basically this exact reason: its hiding bugs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can ban all members that your bot can see.

```py
@bot.command()
async def massban(ctx):
     for member in bot.get_all_members():
         await member.ban()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is here:

```py
await user.ban(user)
```

You do not need to mention the `user` in the brackets. It is enough if you remove the "argument":

```py
@bot.command()
async def massban(ctx):
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await user.ban()
        except:
            pass
```

This command bans all the user from your guild.

Answer (score 0):

so, you need a guild your bot can see.

```
@bot.command()
async def massban(ctx):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  guild = ctx.guild
  for user in ctx.guild.members:
      try:
          await user.ban()
      except:
          pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I know how to fix this as I successfully fixed mine.
So, at `await user.ban(user)` put `await user.ban()` instead.

And then when you run the command it won't work so enable all of the intents for the discord bot then paste this where is the `bot = commands.Bot()`:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="your prefix", intents=intents)
```